# Problema al ejecutar un programa Tragaperras en JAVA

Tags: java

Pues tengo todo el código desarrollado(excepto un par de detalles en el metodo jugar() que ya desarrollaré mas tarde) para hacer un programa que simule una máquina tragaperras y al ejecutar el metodo main me pide la cantidad de crédito que quiero meterle a la máquina para poder hacer jugadas. El caso es que al meter el crédito el programa se queda en blanco y no ejecuta nada y no se a que pueda deberse. Si podeis resolverme este problema sería de gran ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Clase Premio:

```
    package tragaperras;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

//Enumerado de frutas
enum Frutas {
    FRESA, SANDIA, PLATANO, MELOCOTON, PERA;
}

public class Premio {

    //Atributos de instancia
    private int cantidad;
    private ArrayList<Frutas> combinacion;

    //Constructores
    public Premio(int cantidad, Frutas... nFrutas) {
        this.cantidad=cantidad;
        this.combinacion = new ArrayList<Frutas>(Arrays.asList(nFrutas));

    }

    //GETTERS
    public ArrayList<Frutas> getCombinacion() {
        return combinacion;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

}
```

Clase Maquina

```
    package tragaperras;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Maquina {

    //Atributos de instancia
    private double precioJugada;
    private double credito;
    private int nCasillas;
    private boolean jugadaDisponible;
    private ArrayList<Premio> premios;

    //Constructores
    public Maquina(int nCasillas,double precioJugada, Premio...tPremios) {
        this.nCasillas=nCasillas;
        this.precioJugada=precioJugada;
        this.credito = 0;
        this.premios = new ArrayList<Premio>(Arrays.asList(tPremios));
    }

    //Metodos
    public void incrementarCredito(double cantCredito) {
        credito=credito+cantCredito;
    }

    public ArrayList<Frutas> generarCombinacion(){

        ArrayList<Frutas> combinacion = new ArrayList<Frutas>(this.nCasillas);

        Random random = new Random();
        Frutas[] todas = Frutas.values();

        for (int i=0;i<this.nCasillas;i++) {
            Frutas fruta = todas[random.nextInt(todas.length)];
            combinacion.add(fruta);
        }

        return combinacion;
    }

    public ArrayList<Frutas> jugar() {
        if (this.credito>=this.precioJugada) {
            this.jugadaDisponible=true;
            this.credito=this.credito-this.precioJugada;
            generarCombinacion();
            if (generarCombinacion().equals(premios)) {

            } 
        }

        return generarCombinacion();

    }

    //GETTERS
    public double getPrecioJugada() {
        return precioJugada;
    }

    public double getCredito() {
        return credito;
    }

    public int getnCasillas() {
        return nCasillas;
    }

    public boolean isJugadaDisponible() {
        return jugadaDisponible;
    }

    public ArrayList<Premio> getPremios() {
        return premios;
    }

}
```

Clase Main Programa

```
    package tragaperras;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Premio premio1 = new Premio(20,Frutas.FRESA,Frutas.FRESA,Frutas.FRESA);
        Premio premio2 = new Premio(10,Frutas.SANDIA,Frutas.FRESA,Frutas.SANDIA);

        Maquina maquina = new Maquina(3,0.5,premio1,premio2);


        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduca el crédito: ");
        double credito = teclado.nextDouble();
        teclado.nextLine();
        maquina.incrementarCredito(credito);

        while (maquina.isJugadaDisponible()) {
            ArrayList<Frutas> combinacion = maquina.jugar();
            System.out.println(combinacion.toString() + " ___ " + maquina.getCredito());
            System.out.println("Pulse intro para volver a jugar");
            teclado.nextLine();
        }

        teclado.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente se te queda parado? ¿Justo después de pedirte el crédito? ¿No será porque justo a continuación vuelves a ejecutar teclado.nextLine() y se te queda esperando que pulses algo en la consola? ¿Has probado a depurar?

Comment: Si, es justo despues de introducir el crédito. He depurado pero al llegar a la linea de double credito = teclado .nextDouble(); se para, no sigue hasta el siguiente breakpoint. He probado quitando los teclado.nextLine() y sigue pasando lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error lo tienes en el atributo `jugadaDisponible` de la Clase Maquina que no se inicializa en ninguna parte por ende es `false`.

Cuando pasa por el `while` no entra porque la condición retorna `false`.

Yo la inicialize en el constructor y el programa se ejecuto sin problemas

```java
public Maquina(int nCasillas, double precioJugada, Premio... tPremios) {
     this.nCasillas = nCasillas;
     this.precioJugada = precioJugada;
     this.credito = 0;
     this.premios = new ArrayList<Premio>(Arrays.asList(tPremios));
     this.jugadaDisponible= true;
}
```

Comment: No puede ser nulo porque es un `boolean` tipo de dato primitivo que no puede ser null y que si no se inicializa con un valor, toma el valor `false` por defecto. Como mucho se saldría del bucle sin llegar a entrar.

Comment: Tienes razón ya lo edite en la respuesta

Comment: El tema es que al crear el objeto Maquina la jugada disponible tiene que ser false porque es como si la maquina no tuviera crédito para poder jugar, si lo inicializo a true es como si no hiciera falta meter credito para poder jugar. No se si me explico bien. El valor tiene que cambiar a true cuando se le mete crédito a la maquina. Entonces yo creo que el problema tiene que estar en el metodo jugar o algo así.

Comment: Claro pero lo quise decir que te falta cambiar el atributo `jugadaDisponible` a `true` para que te funcione yo lo puse en el controlador como ejemplo

Comment: En tal caso deberías hacerlo en el método de `incrementarCredito` que donde seteas los crédito para jugar, pero solo es mi opinión

Comment: Si, ya hice el cambio de variable en el método de incrementar crédito. Gracias.